# Storing OAuth secret in the open-source project

Tags: c++, oauth, dropbox

I'm using Dropbox **OAuth** in my desktop application for uploading files. However, my app is **open-source**, so I have no idea how to store the *app secret*. If I don't hide it, any other program will be able to use my app identity.

I could include the separate header file (C++) with secret keys and don't distribute this header in my sources, but, in my opinion, such repository will look a bit inadequate (correct me if I'm wrong).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the typical thing to do here is to omit the app key and secret from your source and give people instructions for how to create their own app key and secret via the Dropbox website.

Answer (score 1):

I think you hit the nail on the head - the nature of sharing your software as FOSS means that anybody can duplicate any portion of your program's functionality; this also implies that anyone can design software to impersonate any aspect of your program.  This is by no means a bad thing; it's just the nature of open source.

If you selectively hide your app secret, all you're doing is preventing others from building your source and getting the same result as you get when you build it.  That's pretty much contrary to open source principles IMO.

If the problem is the risk of app deletion on some marketplace due to secret getting compromised, then one solution is to generate a new app secret at build time, for each individual build - although this is far from ideal.